# Why does the browser request no data？java's ServerSocket and socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking, browser, serversocket

Recently, I wanted to verify a computer network problem. So, I wrote a program, and at first it worked. But occasionally, it makes an error - outof memory error. After testing, I found that my code is wrong. I read a byte directly and then convert it into a character. I don't know why. Sometimes there is no data in the connection. The program only reads a - 1, and then converts - 1 into a character, But the whole program can't stop. So, I want to know, what is the reason for this mistake? I don't know whether it's the browser or the program. I hope you can help me solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```java
package org.dragon;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class CheckServer {
    public static final String CRLF = "\r\n";
    public static final String BLANK = " ";
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080)) {
            while (true) {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                new Thread(()-> {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    try {
                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                        char ch;
                        while ((ch = (char) in.read()) != '\n') {
                            sb.append(ch);
                        }

                        System.out.println(sb); 
                        byte[] body = "I love you yesterday and today!".getBytes();
                    
                        // create response header
                        StringBuilder headerBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        headerBuilder.append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK").append(CRLF)
                        .append("Host:").append(BLANK).append(client.getInetAddress().getHostName()).append(CRLF)
                        .append("Content-Type:").append(BLANK).append("application/json").append(CRLF)
                        .append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:").append(BLANK).append("*").append(CRLF)
                        .append("Content-Length:").append(BLANK).append(body.length).append(CRLF)
                        .append(CRLF);
                        
                        System.out.println(headerBuilder);
                        // response header
                        byte[] header = headerBuilder.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        // return response message
                        out.write(header);
                        out.write(body);
                        // flush the stream
                        out.flush();
                    
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("StringBuilder object's length: " + sb.length());
                        System.out.println("StringBuilder object's content: ");
                        System.out.println(sb);
                        System.out.println("========================");
                    } finally {
                        if (client != null) {
                            try {
                                client.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

When I use browser to visit the http://localhost:8080, If you visit many times
or after a while, there will be errors. And, here is the Error infomation:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Host: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 
Content-Type: application/json 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
Content-Length: 31


java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
StringBuilder object's length: 1207959550
StringBuilder object's content: 
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:649)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
    at org.dragon.CheckServer.lambda$0(CheckServer.java:28)
    at org.dragon.CheckServer$$Lambda$1/135721597.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at org.dragon.CheckServer.lambda$0(CheckServer.java:56)
    at org.dragon.CheckServer$$Lambda$1/135721597.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I attempt to print the sb, it occur an Exception, but I think this is not a problem.
And I really want to know why the code will read no data?

```java
    char ch;
    while ((ch = (char) in.read()) != '\n') {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
```

Is the request sent by the browser empty?

**Notice:** I know that I can't directly convert the read byte into a character. I have to judge whether it is - 1. If it is - 1, I can ignore it. But I don't understand why there is such a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### infinite stringbuilder

As written, your code reads data off the wire and adds it to a stringbuilder, which is a thing in memory.

Your code will continue to do this until the character `\n` is encountered. Note that the `read()` method will return -1, and will continue to do so forever, if the stream has ended. That means you add an endless sequence of `-1` characters to the stringbuilder, forever. Except of course, 'forever' isn't quite forever: Once you run out of memory to store that infinite sequence of -1, you get this.

The solution is trivial: Stop looping when that .read() call returns -1, or \n. Save the result in a local variable and you can then simply check. Something like:

```
while (true) {
    int ch = in.read(); // do NOT cast to char, you can't detect -1 that way
    if (ch == -1 || ch == '\n') break;
    sb.append((char) ch); // cast here.
}
```

Don't ignore -1 – end the loop on -1. There is no more data coming. **ever**. If you're waiting for a newline char it will never occur.

### Okay so why is this happening?

Hey, it's networking. You don't get any guarantees.